# How to construct a polynomial with certain restraints

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Construct a fifth-degree polynomial $p(x)$ in the interval ${\cal I} = [-3,3]$ that meets these conditions:

- $p(x)$ has 5 different roots, each in the interval ${\cal I}$.
- The coefficient of the leading term, $x^5$, must be equal to 1.
- $\max [\ |p(x)| \ ] \leq 1/5, x \in {\cal I}$

I am not sure if this polynomial exists.

Comment: Is that $E$ meant to be $\in$?

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes, I am sorry I am not familiar with Latex.You can edit it if you want

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes the roots must be in [-3,3] and should be real numbers

Comment: Suggestion:  $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)$ where $\{ a, b, c, d, e \} \in [-3,3]$.  Also, $f(0) = -a b c d e$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Suggestion $(x-3)(x-a)x(x+a)(x+3)$, find the maximum as a function of $a \in (0,3)$ and hope there's an $a$ that works.

Comment: @EthanBolker:  *Hope*?  Why must we assume that the function is symmetric?  or that it vanishes at the endpoints?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I've no reason to believe that the function must look like that. It's what I would try first because it's easy.  Perhaps I should have made that clear in the comment. The answer provided shows it wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such polynomial exists.

Let $p(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $5$. Let $q(t)=\dfrac{1}{3^5}p(3t)$.

Then $q(t)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $5$ and
$$
\max_{x \in [-3,3]} |p(x)| = 3^5 \max_{t \in [-1,1]} |q(t)| \geq \dfrac{3^5}{2^{4}} > \frac15
$$
because the monic polynomial of degree $5$ with minimal norm in $[-1,1]$ is $\dfrac{1}{2^{4}}T_{5}(t)$, where $T_5$ is the $5$-th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). The minimal norm is $\dfrac{1}{2^{4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the roots of $p$ are $a<b<c<d<e$, then the subintervals of $[-3,3]$ where $p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)$ is positive are $(a,b),(c,d),$ and $(e,3]$.  To make the maximum value of $p(x)$ as small as possible, the idea is to make the intervals where it is positive very short.  That means we want $a$ and $b$ to be very close together, $c$ and $d$ to be very close together, and $e$ to be very close to $3$.

So, fix $\epsilon>0$ and whatever values of $a$ and $c$ you want (with $a<c-\epsilon$ and $c+\epsilon<3-\epsilon$) and consider $p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)$ where $b=a+\epsilon$, $d=c+\epsilon$, and $e=3-\epsilon$.  Note that then if $x\in (a,b)$, $|x-a|$ and $|x-b|$ are at most $\epsilon$, so $|p(x)|<6^3\epsilon^2$ (the other factors in $p(x)$ have absolute value less than $6$, the diameter of $[-3,3]$).  Similarly we have $|p(x)|<6^3\epsilon^2$ for all $x\in (c,d)$ and $|p(x)|<6^4\epsilon$ for all $x\in (e,3]$.  So, as long as we pick $\epsilon$ small enough, $|p(x)|$ will always be at most $1/5$ on any interval where $p(x)$ is positive, and so $p(x)\leq 1/5$ on all of $[-3,3]$.